# CherryPy server errors log

Tags: cherrypy

Where does the CherryPy server write its error logs to? I have installed CherryPy and fired up the server with python3.2

```
    from cherrypy import wsgiserver

    def my_crazy_app(environ, start_response):
        status = '200 OK'
        response_headers = [("Content-type","text/plain")]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return ['Hello world!']

    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(
                ('0.0.0.0', 80), my_crazy_app,
                server_name='www.cherrypy.example')
    server.start()
```

When I go to the url the page does not load and no errors are printed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the error or access log file name.  You can do so in a config file...

```
[global]
log.error_file = 'Web.log'
log.access_file = 'Access.log'
```

or in a Python file...

```
cherrypy.config.update({'log.error_file': 'Web.log',
                'log.access_file': 'Access.log'
               })
```

I'm thinking your getting a "Port 80 not free" error.  Try changing your port to 8080.

Andrew

Comment: Quotes needed around 'Web.log' and 'Access.log' so the path is recognized as a string